# code or tutorial for how to make call from iphone application without quitting the application in iphone 4

Tags: iphone, call

How can i make a call from iphone application with out quitting the application in iphone 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 4, your application doesn't actually quit unless you want it to, or memory is scarce. It'll just move to the background.

This page has lots of information on multitasking:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1